# UIScrollView horiztal paging

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I want to create an iphone application that has horizontal paging views. I have seen many examples online with the horizontal paging but I haven't seen one with vertical scrolling for each of the page. In other word, I want to have a horizontal paging, and each of the page will scroll vertically (up and down).Thanks for your help!

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need 2 properties to be set in order to page a scrollView:

```
/* set the frame of the scrollView */
[scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,280,340)];

/* make sure the scrollView snaps (pages) */
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

/* this tells you the size of the content, width, height */
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(280, 680)];
```

Where **`280` is the width**, and **`680` is the height**, you would take the original height of the scrollview *(here it is **340**)* and multiply it by the number of pages you want. So in this example, there would be 2 vertical pages. 2 because 340 x 2 is 680, make sense?

Same method would apply to horizontal paging, only you would multiply the width of the scrollView.

Comment: thanks, but the problem i am facing now is when I move the page diagonally, it doesn't stick to the four bounds. It moves freely.

Comment: https://github.com/ykyuen/ScrollViewWithPaging         this is the source code I am working on,

Comment: I change scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * kNumberOfPages, scrollView.frame.size.height); WITH scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * kNumberOfPages, scrollView.frame.size.height+500);

Comment: You should definitely use http://pastie.org .. I am not quite sure what you are trying to do anymore, your original statement claims to want to scroll up and down. You have this scrolling left to right.

Comment: Sorry, Ok, let me rephrase my problem here. In my app I use a page control and a UIScrollView to page horizontally, I'd like to be able to enable vertical scrolling on each page. Now I know you can nest UIScrollViews in order to achieve this, there is however one problem in my project. Each of the pages uses a view controller consisting of a view, with a background image (different image for each page). This background image should not move while scrolling up and down.